Who is exempt from Jizyah in the Shafi'i school of thought?
I came across this claim:

Our school (Shafi'i) insists upon the payment of the poll-tax by sickly persons, old men, even if decrepit, blind men, monks, workmen, and poor persons incapable of exercising a trade.[5] As for people who seem to be insolvent at the end of the year, the sum of the poll tax remained as debt to their account until they should become solvent." Imam nawawi

My question is what is the official Shafi school opinion on who is exempt from paying Jizyah.

Ask one focused and concise question per post and format your question clearly.

There is consensus that Jizyah is not to be levied on children and insane people. The view of the vast majority is that Jizyah is also not to be levied on women and slaves.
It is agreed upon that Jizyah is to be levied on a poor person if he has the ability to earn (the amount may be lower compared to a rich person but some tax is imposed). There is disagreement on when he does not have the ability to earn: The view of the Shafi'is is that Jizyah is levied on him but it will be considered a debt that he owes to be paid when he is able to afford it.
As for Monks \ Priests then if they mix with the people and assist in fighting such as by giving advice or commands then there is agreement that Jizyah is to be levied on them. If they live in seclusion and are primarily engaged in worship then there exists disagreement: The view of the Shafi'is is that Jizyah is levied on them.
There is disagreement on men who are old, blind, crippled etc. The view of the Hanafis is that Jizyah is not levied on them. The view of the Malikis is that Jizyah is levied on them if they have wealth. The view of the Shafi'is is that Jizyah is to be levied on them regardless, if they are wealthy they can afford it and if they are poor then that is covered above.
The evidence of the Shafi'is for levying Jizyah, on these categories of people, includes:

The verse of the Quran:

قاتلوا الذين لا يؤمنون بالله ... حتى يعطوا الجزية عن يد وهم صاغرون
Fight those who do not believe in Allah ... until they give the jizyah willingly while they are humbled.
— Quran 9:29

This verse commands the Muslims to fight the disbelievers until they pay Jizyah. Every disbeliever is included in it by default and the verse makes no exception for when the disbeliever is poor, monk, old, blind, crippled etc. Nor is there any other valid evidence (according to the Shafi'is) which excludes these categories from the verse.

The hadith:

يأخذ من كل حالم - يعني محتلما - دينارا
When the Prophet (ﷺ) sent Mu'adh ibn Jabal to the Yemen, he ordered him to take  one dinar for every adult (male)
— Abu Dawud

Adult men who happen to be old, monks, poor, blind, crippled are included in  كل حالم (all adult males) and the hadith makes no mention of an exception for them.

The athar:

أن عمر كتب إلى عماله: لا تضربوا الجزية على النساء والصبيان، ولا تضربوها إلا على من جرت عليه الموسى
Umar wrote to his governors: Do not impose Jizya on the women and the children, and do not impose it except on one who has shaveable pubic hair (adult)
— Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah

Adult men who happen to be old, monks, poor, blind, crippled are not women and children they are included in those from whom Jizya is taken.

Jizyah is taken as a substitute for execution. It is permitted to kill the listed categories in the Shafi'i madhab, see Why does the Shafi'i Madhab permit killing all non Muslim adult males during Jihad?. So Jizyah will be imposed on them when they are spared.

Jizyah is a price for being allowed to stay in the Dar al-Islam. The listed categories would be liable to pay it just as they are liable to pay for anything else such as their rent.


Ref:

والمذهب وجوبها على زمن وشيخ هرم وأعمى وراهب وأجير وفقير كسب فإذا تمت سنة وهو معسر ففي ذمته حتى يوسر
— Mughni al-Muhtaaj


Interesting a 2 more questions is there any difference of opinion in the Shafi school that allows an exemption for the old and their like and 2nd what is the view of the other schools of thought on this issue
